# Prevent repeating of html elements in nested foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 inner collections i.e AirAirPricingInfo and CommonV420BookingTraveler. The first foreach with pricinginfo is to read baseprice,EquivalentBasePrice,Taxes and the second foreach with passengerdetails is to read firstname,lastname and dob. There are only **3:3** items in both collections when combined it should display 3 divs **"term-description"** with details of both collections i.e AirAirPricingInfo and CommonV420BookingTraveler. But its dislaying 6 divs combined please suggest

```
@foreach(var priceinginfo in Model.SOAPEnvelope.SOAPBody.UniversalAirCreateReservationRsp.UniversalUniversalRecord.AirAirReservation.AirAirPricingInfo)
{
    foreach (var passengerdetails in Model.SOAPEnvelope.SOAPBody.UniversalAirCreateReservationRsp.UniversalUniversalRecord.CommonV420BookingTraveler)
    { 
        <dl class="term-description">
            <dt>First name:</dt>
            <dd>@passengerdetails.CommonV420BookingTravelerName.First</dd>
            <dt>Last name:</dt>
            <dd>@passengerdetails.CommonV420BookingTravelerName.Last</dd>
            <dt>Passenger Type:</dt>
            <dd>@passengerdetails.Gender</dd>
            <dt>Date of Birth</dt>
            <dd>@passengerdetails.DOB</dd>
            @*<dt>Booking/Cabin Class</dt>
                <dd>@pricing.AirBookingInfo</dd>
                <dt>Baggage Allowance</dt>
                <dd>@pricing.AirFareInfo.First().AirBaggageAllowance.AirMaxWeight.Value @pricing.AirFareInfo.First().AirBaggageAllowance.AirMaxWeight.Unit</dd>*@
            <dt style="width: 100%">
                <table class="table">
                    <tr class="warning" style="text-align: left; color: #000">
                        <td class="col-md-2">Fare</td>
                        <td class="col-md-2">Equivalent Fare</td>
                        <td class="col-md-5">Taxes</td>
                        <td>Total Fare</td>
                    </tr>
                    @*  *@
                </table>
                <tr class="warning" style="text-align: left; color: #000">
                    @*<td class="col-md-2">AED 1200.00</td>*@
                    <td class="col-md-2">@priceinginfo.BasePrice</td>
                    <td class="col-md-2">@priceinginfo.EquivalentBasePrice</td>
                     <td class="col-md-5">@priceinginfo.Taxes</td>
                     <td>@priceinginfo.TotalPrice</td>
                </tr>
            </dt>
            @*<dt style="width: 100%">@pricing.AirFareCalc</dt>*@
            @*@*<dt style="width: 100%">BLR EY X/AUH EY DXB Q BLRDXB25.00Q BLRDXB10.00 130.22ULPRRTEY/YS EY X/AUH EY BLR Q DXBBLR10.00 130.22ULPRRTEY/YS NUC305.44END ROE64.331</dt>*@
            @*<dt style="width: 100%">NON ENDO/ NONREF</dt>*@
        </dl>
    }
}
```

Comment: Move AirAirPricingInfo specific data out of the second foreach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fimiliar with your data model but if there is any relationship between AirAirPricingInfo and CommonV420BookingTraveler then you can have if block in the inner loop to only emit the CommonV420BookingTraveler which is the related to the AirAirPricingInfo being processed by the 
outter loop.

```
@foreach(var priceinginfo in Model.SOAPEnvelope.SOAPBody.UniversalAirCreateReservationRsp.UniversalUniversalRecord.AirAirReservation.AirAirPricingInfo)
{
    foreach (var passengerdetails in Model.SOAPEnvelope.SOAPBody.UniversalAirCreateReservationRsp.UniversalUniversalRecord.CommonV420BookingTraveler)
    {
    if(passengerdetails.AirAirPricingInfo == priceinginfo)
    {
      //continue with your logic
    }
    }
}
```